# WordPress Register Block with metadata

Tags: php, json

I am trying to register a block using the metadata from the block.json

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:       FAQ Block
 * Description:       It is using the description from faq-block.php, not from block.json.
 * Requires at least: 6.1
 * Requires PHP:      7.0
 * Version:           1.0.0
 * Author:            Marcel Nitzsche
 * Text Domain:       faq
 *
 * @package           faq
 */

/**
 * Registers the block using the metadata loaded from the `block.json` file.
 * Behind the scenes, it registers also all assets so they can be enqueued
 * through the block editor in the corresponding context.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_type/
 */

namespace marcelnitzsche\faq;

function create_block_faq_block_block_init() {

    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build');

}

add_action( 'init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\create_block_faq_block_block_init' );
```

```js
/**
 * Registers a new block provided a unique name and an object defining its behavior.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-registration/
 */
import { registerBlockType } from "@wordpress/blocks";

/**
 * Lets webpack process CSS, SASS or SCSS files referenced in JavaScript files.
 * All files containing `style` keyword are bundled together. The code used
 * gets applied both to the front of your site and to the editor.
 *
 * @see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts#using-css
 */
import "./style.scss";

/**
 * Internal dependencies
 */
import Edit from "./edit";
import save from "./save";
import metadata from "./block.json";

/**
 * Every block starts by registering a new block type definition.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-registration/
 */
registerBlockType(metadata, {
    /**
     * @see ./edit.js
     */
    edit: Edit,

    /**
     * @see ./save.js
     */
    save,
});
```

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "marcelnitzsche/faq-block",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "FAQ Block",
    "category": "widgets",
    "icon": "smiley",
    "description": "Example block scaffolded with Create Block tool.",
    "attributes": {
        "question": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "supports": {
        "align": ["wide", "full"],
        "anchor": true,
        "color": {
            "gradients": true,
            "text": true
        }
    },
    "styles": [
        {"name": "faq", "label": "FAQ", "isDefault": true}
    ],
    "textdomain": "faq-block",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css"
}
```

It is not using the metadata from the block.json-file though.

[image]

There should not be an update available either. :D

[image]

Comment: The update is likely because there is already a plugin on WordPress.org named `faq-block`. Since update notifications are purely based on plugin name and version number you should give your plugin a unique name to avoid receiving updates for another plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @JacobPeattie but isn't that, what the namespace is for? Avoiding plugins with the same name from different authors to cause a conflict.

Comment: You seem to be confusing plugins and blocks. The details shown in your screenshot are pulled from your main plugin file. The block.json file details are used by the block in the editor. Blocks have namespaces, plugins do not.

Comment: I added a picture of the folder structure. I created the inital files with  `npx @wordpress/create-block`. Isn't that the supposed way? The .php file was created by the package.

Comment: The description of the create block package is: "Create Block is an officially supported tool for scaffolding a WordPress plugin that registers a block". So there's a plugin with a block.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/getting-started/create-block/

Comment: Yes, and? I've explained the issue. Are you still confused?

Comment: So, in conclusion, there is no solution for my issue and I should just change to name to something weird and unique?